# Does p4V have a good way to merge integration files without having to click a lot?

Tags: perforce, p4v

When performing integrations, sometimes you need to merge files. The old Perforce GUI (P4Win) had a nice <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> hotkey I could use to run my merge tool quckly and easily.

In P4V, I find I need to right-click the file, click on Resolve, and then click on Run Merge Tool.  Alternatively I can right click, <kbd>O</kbd>, <kbd>O</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and then click on Run Merge tool.  This is a pain, especially when I need to resolve dozens of files.

Is there a way to make it better?

Answer (score 1):

Right-click on your pending changelist and select "Resolve Files..."  That will walk you through each file.